# ASP.NET MVC передать значение textarea в контроллер

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день, 
при передачи формы в контроллер переменная **string eText**, которая должна содержать значение textarea равна null. Может кто сталкивался с подобным или сможет подсказать в чем проблема?

**view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateEvent", "CMS", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "eventForm" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="eId" name="eId" />
    <input type="hidden" id="eImgsDelete" name="eImgsDelete" />
    <input type="hidden" id="eTags" name="eTags" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-2 bb-grey">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="eDatepoint">Дата</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" id="eDatepoint" name="eDatepoint">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-2 bb-grey">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="eTitle">Заголовок</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eTitle" name="eTitle" placeholder="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-2 bb-grey">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="eText">Текст</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="eText" name="eText" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>            
        ...
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Сохранить</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [CheckAuthorized]
    public JObject UpdateEvent(int? eId, string eImgsDelete, string eTags, DateTime eDatepoint, string eTitle, string eText, HttpPostedFileBase ePreview, HttpPostedFileBase[] eImgs)
    {
        dynamic answer = new JObject();
        answer.error = false;

        try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }            

        return answer;
    }
```

**update** 
Использую в проекте редактор TinyMCE, который повешен на textarea не передающей значение. Если отключить плагин TinyMCE, то значение передается. Теперь нужно понять, чем плагин так мешает.

**fixed**
Спасибо, WebMorda в поиске решения. Повесил обработчик события             beforeSerialize для формы и вызываю **tinyMCE.triggerSave();** Теперь данные на стороне сервера не пустые.

Comment: Попробуйте удалить `enctype`

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: А если попробовать принять как массив строк его? у себя сейчас нет возможности проверить.

Comment: Пробовал изменить string eText на string[] eText. Проблема скорее всего в плагине TinyMCE, но пока не понимаю чем он мешает.

Comment: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950022/tinymce-content-blank-on-mvc-post-action) Посмотрите этот вопрос. Может поможет

Comment: Видел этот вопрос, спасибо. Перед отправкой формы добавил tinyMCE.triggerSave(), но на сервере все равно null

Comment: Повесил tinyMCE.triggerSave() на onchange для textarea, и заработало. WebMorda, спасибо за совет!